# override init() {} was running in loop

Tags: swift, xcode6-beta6

I'm having a trouble with `override init() {}` method which is running in loop. Until it crash with `exc_bad_access`.

```
override init() {
    super.init()
    self.container = UIView()
    self.container.clipsToBounds = false

    println("self.container: \(self.container)")
    self.addSubview(self.container)

    self.contentCenter = CGPointZero
    self.contentScale = 1
    refreshContentTransform()

    self.panRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handlePan:"))
    self.panRecognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1
    self.panRecognizer.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1
    self.addGestureRecognizer(self.panRecognizer)

    self.pinchRecognizer = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handlePinch:"))
    self.addGestureRecognizer(self.pinchRecognizer)
}
```

what could be the trigger?

Before this class init was called. I have a var of that class initialize via `var item = MyVar()`
tracking with break point. it never goes out of that init and somehow continues to loop. :/
I hope someone could give me some advice. thanks.

Comment: It looks like part of your question ended up inside your code block, and reading your question, it isn't really clear what you're asking. You should take a look at this again and see if you can clarify yourself a bit.

Comment: I updated my post. Its just like that.. This is supposed to be like 

self = [super init];
if (self) {//code here } return self;

but in swift self it is readonly. So I'm having trouble achieving the same output. Thanks for the reply btw.

Comment: Nothing's wrong with the code you posted. Can you show the loop you're talking about?

Comment: What does `refreshContentTransform()` do?

Comment: func refreshContentTransform() {
        var transform: CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.contentCenter.x, self.contentCenter.y)
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, self.contentScale, self.contentScale);
        self.container.transform = transform
        println("transform \(transform)")
    }

..my mistake. This was solve and that code above was already altered. I think I have called its class name inside init instead of self. now I'm having trouble with initializing a self from nib file.